# Python-Convert int to bin

Tags: python, int, converters, bin

I have a number on int format, but I want that the same algarisms make a binary number
so I could make binary operations with that number, how can I do that?

number = 1010111

Answer (score 2):

Python includes the [builtin function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin) `bin()` to do this.

However, this just creates a string of the binary representation. This is completely unnecessary to do any sort of "binary operations" on a number, which can all be done on a normal `int`.

Answer (score 0):

use the builtin function `bin()` to output in binary and the `0b1010111` format for input.